# Вывод блоков с использованием cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookie

Разметка например такая

```
<div id="Player1"></div>
<div id="Player2"></div>
...
<div id="Player100"></div>
```

В cookies браузера записываются id блоков например

```
Player1
Player5
Player30
```

и тп

Как вывести блоки с id, которых нет в куках?
Либо прописать `display:none;` для блоков которые есть в куках.

У меня записывается в куки вот этим скриптом

```
var views = {
    save: function(b){
        var a = localStorage['level'];
        a = a ? JSON.parse(a) : new Object;

        var i = a[b] ? a[b] : new Object;
        i[b] = b; a[b] = i;

        if(b && !$('#Player' + b).hasClass('views')){
            $('#Player' + b).addClass('views');
            localStorage['level'] = JSON.stringify(a);

            console.log('#Player' + b + ' addClass views');
        }
    },
    check: function(b){
        var a = localStorage['level'];
        a = a ? JSON.parse(a) : new Object;

        $(b).find('a').each(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('Player', '');

            if(a[id]){
                $('#Player' + id).addClass('views');

                console.log('#Player' + id + ' addClass views');
            }
        });
    }
}

views.check('.play_list');

$(function(){
    $('.play').click(function(e){
        var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('Player', '');
        views.save(id);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('.clear').click(function(e){
        localStorage['level'] = '';
        $('.play_list').find('a').each(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('Player', '');

            if(id && $('#Player' + id).hasClass('views')){
                $('#Player' + id).removeClass('views');

                console.log('#Player' + id + ' removeClass views');
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: В вашем примере кода, cookie _не используются_!

Comment: `var i = a[b] ? a[b] : new Object; i[b] = b; a[b] = i;` Такое ощущение, что я читаю минифицированный код :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Cookies:**

```
Object.keys(Cookies.get()).forEach(function (idPlayer) {
    $('#' + idPlayer).hide();
})
```

Посмотрите **[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/6s2j50xv/1/)**

NB: Для упрощения кода использую маленькую библиотеку [js-cookies](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie), можно делать и читая `document.cookie` если не хотите её добавить.

**localStorage:**

*localStorage* обычный объект, со своиствами и значениями. Поэтому, допустим сохраняете идентификаторы при помощи `localStorage.setItem('Player1', '...')`, процесс будет сеовсем подобный:

```
Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(function (idPlayer) {
    $('#' + idPlayer).hide();
})
```

**[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/6s2j50xv/2/)**

Comment: А как использовать с **localStorage**

Comment: Совсем подобно, добавил в ответе.

Comment: Помогите переделать мой код на нормальный. Он всего лишь добавляет класс `views` (с запоминанием) к ссылке(с `#Player`) на которую нажали.

Comment: #Player(тут разные числа)